# Auto Saving through VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Autosave()

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\PC\Desktop\NAME.xlsm" _
, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

In the above code I was trying to change the file name "NAME" to value of range "A1" , however it throws an error always. Is there any way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To SaveAs Value of range "A1"

```
Sub Autosave()
    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Text

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Users\PC\Desktop\" & FileName _
    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```